# Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires a TTY

Tags: interface, vagrant, tty

Problem: vagrant up fails with the error below. I am running vagrant on Windows 7 and the base box is Ubuntu )( files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box ).

how can it be fixed?

```
    vagrant.bat up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Available bridged network interfaces:
1) Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O Acceleration
2) Intel(R) PRO/1000 PL Network Connection
Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires
a TTY. Most actions in Vagrant that require a TTY have configuration
switches to disable this requirement. Please do that or run Vagrant
with TTY.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

thanks

Answer (score 21):

[This](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6026#issuecomment-126916343) worked for me on cygwin:

> Or add this to ~/.bashrc:

```
export VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS=cygwin
```

Then I got the "Vagrant displays a message that it needs to run some internal upgrades..."

**Edit -** Oops! Spoke to soon. During its updates, I got `Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...` until timeout :P

**Edit 2 -** [I was able to fix it](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4839#issuecomment-75484449) by setting `config.ssh.private_key_path` to the `.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` in my Windows user's home directory.

Comment: I had this issue under Cygwin and simply setting the environment variable as you advised worked for me.  I did not need to do anything else.  I suspect that Vagrant had become confused about the environment somehow.

Comment: I also simple set export VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS=cygwin in the bashrc file for cygwin and it worked perfectly.

Comment: adding export VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS=cygwin to the ~/.bashrc did the trick in my windows cygwin setup thx! As a side note i also made the cygwin application run as Administrator.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error while destroying a Vagrant Box. I simply added `-f` and it did the job.

```
vagrant destroy m001 -f
```

This is happening because when script attempts `vagrant destroy`, Vagrant asks for [Yes/No] confirmation. Adding `-f` skips that.

Comment: I had the issue with "vagrant box remove", and `-f`fixed that as well. Cheers.

Comment: Can confirm that using -f solves "vagrant box remove" issue.

Answer (score 14):

I got the same error after upgrading Vagrant from 1.4 to 1.6.3 (Windows 7).

Running `VAGRANT_HOME\bin\vagrant.exe` manually resolved this issue for me:

- Execute VAGRANT_HOME\bin\vagrant.exe
- Vagrant displays a message that it needs to run some internal upgrades
- "Press any key to continue"...
- Once the process finished (it took several minutes), I was able to proceed with Vagrant instance launch as usual.

Comment: This is true for any OS. Running vagrant on OSX solved same issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by Vagrant finding multiple Ethernet interfaces that can be used as public network and Vagrant cannot decide which one to use.

There are 3 options:

1. Deactivate one of the 2 adapters, so that Vagrant can use the other
2. [Specify the Ethernet adapter](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) you would like Vagrant to use in the vagrantfile. Like this:

   ```
   app.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "Intel(R) PRO/1000 PL Network Connection"
   ```
3. Running the vagrant executable manually as already described in Al Belsky's answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows and are starting Vagrant through MinGW (Git Bash for example) and get this message, try running it once through Windows' default `cmd.exe`. You are then able to answer the question about your network adapters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `Vagrant 1.7.4`

Execute the below code before running vagrant up:

```
export VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS=cygwin
```

That will eliminate the exiting of vagrant and will allow you to choose Network Interface.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be caused by not having Hardware Virtualization enabled in BIOS.

Also encountered this with Windows 10, when Vagrant cannot properly detect OS.

Answer (score 0):

also can happen if you have both vmware and virtual box installed and you try to use MinGW.