# Vagrant error when trying to install homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant

So i'm new to the whole Laravel scene. I'm trying to install it on Vagrant. But get this error.

Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires
a TTY. Most actions in Vagrant that require a TTY have configuration
switches to disable this requirement. Please do that or run Vagrant
with TTY.

Any ideas. 
O/s = Win10

Answer (score 0):

- Execute VAGRANT_HOME\bin\vagrant.exe
- Vagrant displays a message that it needs to run some internal upgrades
- "Press any key to continue"...
- Once the process finished (it took several minutes), I was able to proceed with Vagrant instance launch as usual.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086383/2977133