# "Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI" - Homestead setup

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I'm attempting to set up a homestead environment but I seem to be falling at the first hurdle.

After installing homestead and running

> vagrant box add laravel/homestead

I get the following error

> Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires
>   a TTY. Most actions in Vagrant that require a TTY have configuration
>   switches to disable this requirement. Please do that or run Vagrant
>   with TTY.

I've already seen the article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633276/vagrant-is-attempting-to-interface-with-the-ui-in-a-way-that-requires-a-tty) but this doesn't help with my particular issue. Anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Can you list out the exact steps you followed to install homestead? The homestead box doesn't require any UI actions.

Comment: I was following a few tutorials and the steps were all the same.

1) Install Virtual Box,
2) Install Vagrant,
3) Run "vagrant box add laravel/homestead

Comment: What does your ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml file look like?

Comment: I don't have one, haven't even got to that bit yet (apologies I hit return to early on the above reply, I've edited it with more info now)

Comment: You'll need one before you can start using homestead. There is a homestead init script in the Homestead repo you checked out. It's worth a try.

Comment: I just ran "vagrant init" then again tried to run "vagrant box add laravel/homestead" and still have the same issue

Comment: have you run the homstead init.sh script? You need that yaml file

Comment: I have yes, it's created the yaml file but still getting the same problem with the "vagrant box" command.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling vagrant?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For whatever reason (possibly the admin reasons as mentioned by txst_gilley) in CMD prompt it wouldn't run.

Having installed MinTTY with the latest version of GIT I tried running the command in there and it works fine!

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the commands as administrator in cmd.exe it may may avoid the TTY error. That's the only way I was able to make it work.

Comment: im was using git bash and when i changed to git cmd it started working

Comment: Thank you I was in trouble but its now working after following your advise.