# Laravel homestead with vagrant, virtualbox and git

Tags: git, laravel, vagrant, vagrant-windows

Hello I'm trying to install `laravel/homestead` but when I'm running the command in Git Bash I get an tty error and I don't have any clue how to fix it. I'm running on windows 8.1. Here is the error I get when I run:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires
a TTY. Most actions in Vagrant that require a TTY have configuration
switches to disable this requirement. Please do that or run Vagrant
with TTY.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633276/vagrant-is-attempting-to-interface-with-the-ui-in-a-way-that-requires-a-tty

Answer (score 0):

Right click on either command prompt, or Git Bash and run as administrator. Then try run the command. It worked for me.